# System app upgrade is missing upgrade entitlement Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following error message while trying to run the app in Simulator.

> system app upgrade is missing upgrade entitlement Xcode

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Remove the existing application from the device and Run again.

Comment: I cannot see any cross button on the app to delete it.

Comment: place the pointer over the icon of the app you want to uninstall and hold down the mouse button until all the app icons start to wiggle. Click the app icon's Remove button — the little x that appears in the upper-left corner of the icon — to make the app Delete

Comment: @v12 thanks for your inputs. But actual problem is, i changed the build file in simulator root folder. that caused the issue. Finally i tried to figure it out. Now it's working fine.